# SQL query output in custom colors

Tags: sql

I have a query like

```
select
  case
      when foo >  0 then 
         'Bar / ' + N'Бар: ' + ' blah blah'
      else 
         'Text / ' + N'текст' + ' blah blah'
  end as 'Baz'
```

Is there a way to have 'Бар: ' and 'текст' outputted in a different colour? 
HTML formatting is not a solution as it needs to output into a non-HTML document

Comment: SQL doesn't knows anything about text formating, colors, HTML or anything. Such changes should be done client-side.

Comment: That what I was afraid of - just needed to get it confirmed :)
Thx

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.

SQL is not about formatting, but about storing and retrieving data efficiently and safely.

Use your front-end (the program that receives the data) to show it (render it) as you see fit.

Comment: That what I was afraid of - just needed to get it confirmed :) Thx